# How to begin writing at the center of the page and moving right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, thesis, center

I am writing the acknowledgement paper in my thesis and from the required guidelines is to write my name at the end of the page beginning from the center of the page and moving right.

Can anyone give me an advice of how to do that please?

Is it by indentation only or is there a smarter way of doing it?

**EDIT:**

Here is a screenshot of how I want the name to look like at the end of the page:

> [image]

**EDIT2:**

Another screenshot

> [image]

Comment: How about `\vspace*{\fill}\noindent\hspace{0.5\textwidth}My first and last name here`?

Comment: I will try it and let you know @Mico

Comment: @Mico the vertical distance is very large between my name and the last sentence in the last paragraph ..... I just need it around 3 `vspace` ...... any correction for your previous comment to meet my requirements?

Comment: Did you try a combination of `center` environment and `vspace`?

Comment: I do not know how to do that@M.A.Bromuela could you show me how please?

Comment: @Happy - Your write-up specified that you had to write your name "at the end of the page"; I interpreted this to mean "at the bottom of the page". If my interpretation was not on  target, and if you actually need, say, `3\baselineskip` of extra vertical whitespace, then by all means do replace `\vspace*{\fill}` with `\vspace*{3\baselineskip}`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to put your names near the end of the page? At the bottom?

Comment: @Mico I am so sorry if my description was unclear and does reflect truly what I want.

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela what I want is exactly as the screenshot I added in my post, sorry if my words was not accurate.

Comment: @Happy - Your screenshot is actually not as informative as you may think it is. In particular, what's not clear if the space above the line is just an ordinary inter-paragraph space. If that's the case, you could just omit the `\vspace` stuff and write (after creating a paragraph break) `\noindent\hspace{0.5\textwidth}Happy`. Aside: It would be quite helpful if you  provided more information of this type up front, so as to eliminate all need for guesswork.

Comment: which line are you referring to in your statement " above the line"?@Mico

Comment: @Mico I edited my post with another screenshot .... does that explain clearly what I wanna say?

Comment: I think I am fine now, your second comment was enough to solve my problem @Mico thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out the combination of `vspace` and `hspace` in the `center` environment right after the paragraph where you want to put your name. Just change the values in `vspace` and `hspace` to your liking.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\hspace{2.5cm} Your first name and last name
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Or alternatively you can try out Mico's suggestion.

[image]

Comment: That is very creative, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The key is `\noindent`.

```
\documentclass{article} % just for the example, it's the same with any class

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}% just to make the text near to the page number
               % so to check the desired alignment

Lastly, I want to thank my wife, Teresa, for having the patience to
watch me sit in front of a CRT and tap keys night after night, with
nothing but this stack of paper to show for it.

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\noindent\hspace{0.5\columnwidth}Andrew J. Moshalik

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for this clarification!